# Why i can't install Windows service by debug window?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I know that we can install windows server via `CMD` and `InstallUtil.exe`, and i want using Debug window to install windows service automatically, i do it :

[image]

i use `CMD` as extrnal program, and `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>InstallUtil.exe` is the path of `installUtill.exe`, and `"E:\HamrahVasCollection\Services\bin\Debug\HamrahSendSMS.exe"` is my project in `bin-->Debug-->HamrahSendSMS.exe` but it does not work, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am not sure that you can do it in such a way.

It looks like CMD does not accept a program name with arguments like start parameters http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true.

Try to set [Install util](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>InstallUtil.exe` directly as an external program in place of the `cmd` and `E:\HamrahVasCollection\Services\bin\Debug\HamrahSendSMS.exe` as command line arguments.

In any case, why to add any level of indirection for such a task - it is just unneeded complication. If indirection does not give any advantage then why to use it?